# How to get only sent messages from specific conversation in Android Studio?

Tags: android, text, sms, mms

```
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = new String[]{"body", "ct_t", "_id", "address"};
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/" + id);
    Cursor c = cr.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

This queries all messages from a specific conversation and I would like only the sent messages to display as I need to distinguish each party of the conversation. 
Is there such a thing as a uri like this:

```
Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/" + id + "/sent/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a couple of columns to your *projection*, and include a *selection* argument in the `query()` call.

```
final String[] projection = {"_id", "address", "body", "ct_t", "type", "msg_box"};
final String selection = "(type = 2 OR msg_box = 2)";
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/" + threadId);
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, null);
```

An SMS message will have a `type` value of `2` when it has been sent. An MMS message will have the same value, but in the `msg_box` column.